# SQL Server Unallocated Space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering what happens if the SQL Server database, the unallocated space gets to 0.00. We currently have a small database and have .64mb left in unallocated space.

Comment: The file will grow as per your file growth settings (assuming there is space available on the drive)

Comment: It will run out of space. What happens after that depends on how you have your growth settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your database. Right click an get properties. Then click on files. You will get a dialog that looks a little like this:

[image]

As long as there is disk space, the files will grow.